# Numpy.genfromtxt method works in windows but not Linux

Tags: python, linux, csv, numpy

I am doing some data crunching and I have built a program for Python in Windows and now I want to run it on my Linux box so it can crunch while I go home to drink beer, etc.

One piece of the code (an important one) ingests some columnar values from a CSV file via Numpy's genfromtxt method.  the snippet of code in question is:

```
rfd_values = np.genfromtxt(file_in, delimiter=',',
             skip_header=1,
             invalid_raise=0,
             usecols = cols)
```

So the idea here is, skip the header, the delimiter is a comma, and give me only the columns from the list callled cols.  This works just hunky-dorey on my Windows laptop (same version of Python and Numpy, 2.6 and 1.5 respectively), but when I run it in Linux it tells me:

*TypeError: genfromtxt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_header'*

I tried putting everything on one line, and changing the quotes around the delimiter keyword, but that didn't seem to work.  Its probably something silly, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.  I looked through a bunch of forums and the Numpy docs and didn't see anything that sounded close to what I was seeing.  I am wondering what it is that I am missing.

I would greatly appreciate any insight.

Thanks in advance!

-Jeff

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Linux using the same versions of numpy and python and a quickly made test file (with dos line endings, even)... Are you sure that you really have numpy 1.5 installed on the Linux side? What does `import numpy; print numpy.__version__` yield?

Comment: @Joe Kington Thanks for your help on this.  It looks like the numpy version is actually 1.3.0

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the `skip_header` kwarg was added in numpy 1.4, so if for some reason 1.5 isn't available in the repos for your linux system, 1.4 should work. Of course, it would be best to upgrade to 1.5. Good luck, at any rate!

Comment: Maybe you can also get away with the `skiprows` parameter to [`loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you're actually using version 1.3 on Linux.  That one has an argument `skiprows` which is the same as `skip_header`.  Considering `numpy.genfromtxt` isn't even in documentation for 1.3, I would guess it was just being tested in 1.3, and the final signature wasn't quite set.  That being said, there is a workaround for your case.  You can use the `names=True` keyword parameter, instead.  In that case, the first row will be used not for data, but to determine the column names (which you can then use, instead of column numbers in the list passed as `usecols`).

But there's another problem.  The `invalid_raise` argument isn't in 1.3 either.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that first just to check, but I think I'll install v1.5 just so that system is up to date.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Great suggestion on using `skiprows`. I changed the line to:  `data = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=",",skiprows=1)` and it worked with numpy v1.3 just fine!  Installing v1.5 involved way too much Fortran compiling for my taste